# css basic for responsive design beginners

Tags: jquery, css, responsive

fantastic stack overflow folk!

I am a n00b with programming, my question is probably not an issue for many of you but I can't make it work by my own and have been trying my best to learn by my self and the support of tutors on my Bootcamp course but sadly cant understand and make it work, can't give any examples because whatever I try it just a miserable failer work and I am a shame to show my failer.
In any case, my issue is with **responsive design** and I don't get it or make it work, is there any site or advice I could get a concrete and clear explanation about?
I am sorry and apologize if my topic is not on the right channel and to disturb the peace of an experienced programmer or software developer.
Best regards

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) which does the *"responsive"* itself.
Just add thi into your documents head

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and a `<div>` wrapper around your content:

```html
<div class="container">
...
</div>
```

Additionally, there are many pre-styled components like navbars or modals

---

If you want to code it yourself, here are some good wiki articles:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

---

PS: there's no need to worry - responsive design seems a bit complicated to everyone at first!